# Failed to connect to MySQL: No such file or directory how to resolve this error?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I got a problem while connecting to db even if my details are accurate like db_name, db_username, db_password and servername also and i tried lot things like i tried to connect it with `mysql_connect()`, `mysqli_connect()` and PDO also but everything fails please some one help me with this problem.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","credai_nashik","$1ePJv0|i,5>","credai_nashik-313235aa94");

// Check connection
if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli -> connect_error;
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Check 1. mysql is running or not. 2. check whether you install php-mysql or not ?

Comment: Are you able to connect with a different client? phpmyadmin? navicat? HeidiSQL? Sequel Pro? Is your MySql server running?

Comment: How you run mysql server?

Answer (score -2):

You should use PDO. Try with this syntax:

```
        $dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $db, $user, $pass, [
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        ]);
```